# Create a function that can draw either on the main canvas or on a createGraphics instance

Tags: p5.js

So, I need a function to draw something but, depending on the case, I might need to either draw on the main canvas or on a createGraphics instance.

Obviously, the following approach works, but I'd need something neater, for more complex drawings:

```
function drawEight(position, targetCanvas)  {
    let {x, y} = position;
    if (targetCanvas != undefined) {
        targetCanvas.circle(x, y-10, 20);
        targetCanvas.circle(x, y-30, 20);
    } else {
        circle(x, y-10, 20);
        circle(x, y-30, 20);
    }
}
```

I tried assigning the main canvas to a variable like so:

`mainCanvas = createCanvas(400,400);`

but then passing mainCanvas to the function:

`drawEight({x:100,y:100}, mainCanvas);`

I get errors as the canvas instance is lacking drawing methods...

Is there a way to achieve what I need or I should give up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, I just need to pass the Window object (this) to the function:

```
function drawEight(position, targetCanvas)  {
    let {x, y} = position;
    targetCanvas.circle(x, y-10, 20);
    targetCanvas.circle(x, y-30, 20);
}
```

and then call it like so (or this :-P):

`drawEight({x:100,y:100}, this);`